# Add css and javascript in android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-studio

I am developing and anroid apps that will show the coundown of a event.For that I used html,css,and java script,it works fine in normal html.But when I put it in android studio,it shows the html page with WebView but it doesn't add the css ad javascript with it .I put java script and css in the same directory.Here is the code

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="flipclock.css" />


</head>
<body>

 <div class="clock-builder-output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flipclock.js"></script>
<style text="text/css">body .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn, body .flip-clock-small-wrapper ul li a div div.inn { color: #CCCCCC; background-color: #333333; } body .flip-clock-dot, body .flip-clock-small-wrapper .flip-clock-dot { background: #323434; } body .flip-clock-wrapper .flip-clock-meridium a, body .flip-clock-small-wrapper .flip-clock-meridium a { color: #323434; }</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 FlipClock.Lang.Custom = { days:'Days', hours:'Hours', minutes:'Minutes', seconds:'Seconds' };
 var opts = {
  clockFace: 'HourCounter',
  countdown: true,
  language: 'Custom'
 };  
 var countdown = 1495943700 - ((new Date().getTime())/1000); // from: 05/28/2017 09:55 am +0600
 countdown = Math.max(1, countdown);
 $('.clock-builder-output').FlipClock(countdown, opts);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the WebView

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";
        WebView view = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you are loading this content into the `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have two folders in which your "index" is located. What could happen is that the external is stepping on the internal so you should put the references of javascript and css in the internal. If this does not work try putting the references on the outside.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

To load external css and javascript files, you need to use a similar url construction as you did when you loaded in the html url into the webview.  So for example, you used:

```
    String url = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";
```

as the URL for the file.  To load the javascript, assuming it's in the same `/asset/www/` directory, you'd say in the HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/flipclock.js"/>
```

A stylesheet file would be loaded as:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/www/myCss.css"/>
```

As an aside, to run injected javascript on-the-fly on pre-KIT-KAT, use:

```
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){####JSGOESHERE####})();");
```

and post-KIT-KAT use:

```
    webView.evaluateJavascript("####JSGOESHERE####", null);
```